# Como incluir a mesma classe em vários arquivos?

Tags: c++, classes

Porque não consigo incluir a mesma classe em vários arquivos tipo assim:

```
#include "familia.h"
class pessoa{

private:
familia *f;
};

-----
#include "pessoa."

class familia{
private:
pessoa *p;
};
```

Comment: Da uma olhada: https://www.vivaolinux.com.br/topico/C-C++/Referencia-cruzada-em-C++

Comment: A resposta resolveu o seu problema? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Se não souber como faz, veja o [tour]. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você e dar uma indicação que houve uma solução satisfatória. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver 15 pontos).

Answer (score 3):

Está tendo problemas porque elas são interdependentes. Precisa garantir que um não chame o outro indefinidamente. Precisa garantir que exista a declaração da classe (não precisa declarar toda ela, mas que ela seja explicitada):

```
#ifndef PESSOA_H
#define PESSOA_H
class Familia;
class Pessoa {
    Familia *f;
};
#endif
```

E depois

```
#ifndef FAMILIA_H
#define FAMILIA_H
class Pessoa;
class Familia {
    Pessoa *p;
};
#endif
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Syntax/ForwardDeclaration.cpp).

Isto chama-se [*forward declaration*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration).

Não se esqueça de colocar guardas no `.cpp` para não carregar cabeçalhos em duplicidade.