# Qual a maneira correta de declarar uma struct em C?

Tags: c, struct, tipagem, sintaxe

Também como renomear os tipos de dados com estruturas?

Tenho dúvida sobre isso por causa de uma Windows Manager que eu uso tem o seguinte código:

```
typedef struct exem exem;

struct exem {
    tiposdedado variavel;
};
```

Comment: O que é `wm`? O que chama de renomear? Está tendo algum problema? Essa é a essencialmente a maneira de declarar a estrutura. Tem alguma dúvida? DÊ mais contexto ao que está tentando perguntar.

Comment: window manager, acho que escrevi errado é atribuir a uma digamos que uma variável aos tipos de dados permitidos na linguagem c

Comment: Você pode [edit] a pergunta e esclarecer melhor do que se trata pergunta. Eu tenho interesse em respondê-la, mas nem sei bem o que quer saber. Pra mim não tem uma pergunta aqui, ainda.

Comment: nesta mesma wm que eu uso tem estruturas declaras de 2 modos 1 o qual citei a cima e o 2 é 

typedef struct {
    tipodedado variavel;
}ex;

no primeiro modo, dentro da função principal eu posso chamar pelo nome da estrutura ex:

ex ex1;

o no segundo eu não posso chamar dentro da função principal

sem chamar o struct antes ex: struct ex ex1;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Declaração de estrutura

```
struct exem {
    tipoDeDado variavel;
};
```

Está declarando a estrutura de dados, ela terá o nome `exem`. Ela poderá ser usada em qualquer parte da aplicação desde que esteja disponível, ou seja, tem que ser nesse mesmo arquivo ou essa declaração [precisa ser incluída onde for usada](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/45021/101) ([outra referência](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/154070/101)). O identificador do nome da estrutura é considerado apenas uma ***tag***.

Para declarar algum valor ou variável que conforme com essa estrutura terá que dizer que está definindo uma `struct`. Assim:

```
struct exem var;
```

Usando dessa forma o seu tipo será uma `struct` que terá uma *tag* para diferenciar de outras existentes, o identificador não funciona sem a palavra-chave.

Quando usa `struct tagName` o compilador considera que ela está declarada em outro local, então alguns erros podem não ser pegos dessa forma. Tem momentos que isso é útil, mas na maioria deles é algo que dá menos robustez ao código. [Veja como compila algo que nem existe](http://ideone.com/YhDFow). Um erro de digitação nem será pego e às vezes é um *bug* chato de achar.

## Declaração de tipo

```
typedef struct exem exem;
```

Agora está criando um novo tipo de dado. Você está declarando o nome dele e como ele é composto. Seu identificador é um **nome de tipo**. O nome do tipo passa ser independente.

No caso ele está dizendo que `exem` (o último) é o nome de tipo que passa existir e ele será composto pela *tag* `exem` (o primeiro que só pode ser usado junto com `struct`, como já viu acima). Nesse exemplo tem o mesmo nome mas são coisas diferentes. Isso é o mesmo que fazer assim:

```
typedef struct exem {
    tipoDeDado variavel;
} exem;
```

Dessa forma em uma única declaração criamos a *tag* e o tipo de dado. Eu acho mais simples fazer isso. Há casos que é interessante ter separado.

Junto ou separado, a vantagem de usar essa forma é que a declaração pode ser simplificada já que você tem um tipo de dado e não apenas uma *tag*  para `struct`. Ficaria assim:

```
exem var;
```

Uma coisa comum que as pessoas fazem para evitar confusões e criar uma convenção para tipos de dados é mudar um pouco o nome, note o maiúsculo do tipo de dado:

```
typedef struct exem {
    tipoDeDado variavel;
} Exem;
```

Assim é possível até mesmo fazer isto na declaração de variáveis desse tipo:

```
Exem exem; //exem é uma variável normal
```

Note que o identificador `exem` não confunde com a *tag*, afinal a *tag* só existe como nome de `struct`.

Há quem prefira usar maiúsculo em ambos. Já digo abaixo porque o maiúsculo é importante (por convenção).

É até normal nem usar um nome de *tag* e só dar nome para o tipo:

```
typedef struct {
    tipoDeDado variavel;
} Exem;
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/Declaration.c).

Precisa entender que criar tipos sem necessidade pode poluir o *namespace* geral. Quando usa-se o `struct` ele meio que está protegendo os nomes necessários, esses nomes só existem nesse contexto, por isso permite ter uma `struct` com um nome e identificadores com o mesmo nome.

Daí usa-se a convenção de tipos serem com maiúsculo para o identificador de tipos, normalmente não usados em identificadores em geral.

`typedef` é uma solução mais robusta com uma desvantagem que pode ser facilmente contornável, por isso prefiro ela sempre que posso.

## *Forward declaration*

Note que no exemplo da pergunta ele está declarando algo que nem existe ainda, isso é chamado [*forward declaration*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/124398/101), claro que ele é mais útil quando estão um pouco mais longe um do outro e tenho uma necessidade, mas imagino que esse seja um exemplo abstrato. É útil para casos que você precisa usar um nome de tipo que só será definido depois, provavelmente por ter referência circular.

Em listas ligadas, árvores ou outras que possuem referências para a própria estrutura é comum definir a *tag* e no nome do tipo. Se usasse o nome do tipo dentro da própria estrutura daria erro porque ele ainda não foi completamente definido. Ou teria que fazer uma *forward declaration* ou usar a forma de `struct tagName`.

## Mais correto

Não existe mais correto, existe gosto ou alguma situação que é interessante fazer separado por questões semânticas. Você pode ter mais de um tipo com a mesma estrutura, provavelmente isso poderá mudar no futuro, então precisa da declaração separada, uma estrutura não pode declarar *inline* mais de um tipo ou fazer a tal da *forward declaration* já citada.

Dei os parâmetros para decidir o mais correto em cada situação.

Note que isso muda um pouco em C++, mas não é o foco da pergunta.

Comment: obrigado pela informação