# Algoritmo de Kruskal ordenado com selection sort

Tags: c, c++, algoritmo, grafo

Estou tentando comparar duas variáveis de um tipo struct, porém está retornando erro.

```
struct aresta{
int v1;
int v2;
int peso;
};
```

...

```
 aresta peso[62816];
    aresta aux;
    int i, j=0;

  for(i=0;  i<(tamanhoVetor - 1); i++){
    int menor = i;
     for(j=(i+1); j<tamanhoVetor; j++){
          if(peso[menor] > peso[j])){ //ERRO RETORNA DESTA LINHA
            menor = j;
          }
        }
        aux = peso[menor];
        peso[menor] = peso[i];
        peso[i] = aux;
        }
```

Código completo: https://pastebin.com/vQTbkY60

Comment: A linha de erro no seu código não está como você tem aqui na pergunta. Altere o código que tem na pergunta de forma a que não seja diferente, e aproveite e coloque também o erro que o compilador dá.

Comment: C++ não suporta comparação entre duas structs, a não ser que você sobrecarrege o operador.

Answer (score 0):

Vendo o seu código percebi algumas coisas que estão irregulares como a declaração do tipo `struct`.( [Como declarar uma *struct* em C](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/162182/60398)). O segundo ponto é que C e C++ não suportam a comparação entre duas `structs`. Segue um código que te ajudará a resolver o seu problema

```
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct {
        int v1;
        int v2;
        int peso;
    } aresta;

aresta menorAresta(aresta a, aresta b){
    //utilizar a forma como você quer comparar a estrutura
    if(a.peso > b.peso){
        return b;
    }
    else{
        return a;
    }
}
int main()
{

    aresta a ={.v1=1,.v2=2,.peso=2};
    aresta b ={.v1=1,.v2=2,.peso=2};
    aresta c =menorAresta(a,b);
    int i = c.peso;
    printf("%d",i);

    return 0;
}
```